# Azure Stream Analytics complex query not returning desired results

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics

This is the input JSON packet.  I'm writing the transformation query in stream analytics to get source and masterTag properties.

```
[{
      "source": "xda",
      "data": 
        [{
            "masterTag": "UNIFY",
            "speed": 180
        }],
      "EventEnqueuedUtcTime": "2018-07-20T19:28:18.5230000Z",
  },
  {
      "source": "xda",
      "data": [{
            "masterTag": "UNIFY",
            "speed": 214
        }],
      "EventEnqueuedUtcTime": "2018-07-20T19:28:20.5550000Z",
  }
]
```

Here is what I've:

```
WITH data AS
(
    SELECT
        source,
        GetArrayElement(data,0) as data_packet 
    FROM input 
)

SELECT 
    source, 
    data_packet.masterTag 
INTO 
    output
FROM data
```

However, this query only returns one element.  How do I update this query to get all elements in the JSON packet?

Comment: Strange, when I try your query with the input you provided I do get two output events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did test with your source data and query, it did get 2 output elements. So,I think you mean how to return all elements with your data array has more elements.

You could use below query:

```
SELECT 
    jsoninput.source, 
    arrayElement.ArrayValue.masterTag
INTO 
    output
FROM jsoninput
CROSS APPLY GetArrayElements(jsoninput.data) AS arrayElement
```

***Json sample:***

```
[{
      "source": "xda",
      "data": 
        [{
            "masterTag": "UNIFY1",
            "speed": 180
        },
        {
            "masterTag": "UNIFY2",
            "speed": 180
        }],
      "EventEnqueuedUtcTime": "2018-07-20T19:28:18.5230000Z",
  },
  {
      "source": "xda",
      "data": [{
            "masterTag": "UNIFY3",
            "speed": 214
        },
        {
            "masterTag": "UNIFY4",
            "speed": 180
        }],
      "EventEnqueuedUtcTime": "2018-07-20T19:28:20.5550000Z",
  }
]
```

***Output:***

[image]

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Although, this wasn't what I required, I might find this useful in the near future.

Answer (score 1):

Try the function GetArrayElements (plural) with a cross apply.

Examples
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/reference/getarrayelements-azure-stream-analytics

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/reference/complex-data-types-stream-analytics#array-data-types